# C compile error using an external function

Tags: c

I'm new to C and feel as if I'm missing some formatting syntax but I can't figure out what exactly. Upon compiling the program with

```
gcc -o test test.c myprintf.c
```

I get the following error

```
expected â;â, â,â or â)â before âsâ
```

I'm sorry if this is some simple overlook on my part, but the format seems to be correct to me. Also this is part of a homework assignment however I tested every function I was responsible for creating separately and they work just fine. I'm omitting the functions I was responsible for writing, if you believe they are needed I will edit them in as it appears to not even access them. The error occurs directly between my first and section function (the blank line between printint and printstring.

#### Simplest test file possible — test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void myprintf(const char *, ...);

int main()
{
  myprintf("Nothing much\n");

  return 0;
}
```

#### myprintf.c

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>


 void printint(int i){
  int temp;
  /*some while loop that shrinks i while outputting the correct char*/

  int ascii = i + '0';
  putchar(ascii);
}

void printstring(char[] s){
  int i = 0;
  /*some while loop that moves through a string using putchar to output the                 corresponding character*/
}

void printhex(int k){
  /*long complicated program involving a series of loops that change a    decimal into a hexidecimal, obviously without using any built in printf or     modifiers*/
}

/*This is the code provided that uses my 3 functions. I assume it all to be correct*/

void myprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
  const char *p;
  va_list argp;
  int i;
  char *s;

  va_start(argp, fmt);

  for (p = fmt; *p != '\0'; p++) {
    if (*p != '%') {
      putchar(*p);
      continue;
    }
    switch (*++p) {
    case 'c':
      i = va_arg(argp, int);
      putchar(i);
      break;

    case 'd':
      i = va_arg(argp, int);
      printint(i);
      break;

    case 's':
      s = va_arg(argp, char *);
      printstring(s);
      break;

    case 'x':
      i = va_arg(argp, int);
      printhex(i);
      break;

    case '%':
      putchar('%');
      break;
    }
  }
  va_end(argp);
}
```

Comment: At some point, you should look into why you get the â characters in the error message.  They're a nuisance if nothing else.  It might be a UTF-8 vs 8859-x code set problem.

Comment: In the compiler error message, it should contain a line number indicating which line the error was on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line is incorrect:

```
void printstring(char[] s){
```

Change that to:

```
void printstring(char s[]){
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfect. Sorry that was such a simple problem, i looked over it a hundred times and didn't notice i declared that parameter wrong.

Comment: No worries. Most of us have been through such mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
void printstring(char[] s){
```

should be:

```
void printstring(char s[]){
```

The square brackets for the array come after the variable name, just as they would if you indexed it with `s[i]` in the code.